# PHP deploying to Linux and Windows

Tags: php, linux, iis, path, include

Depending on whether I'm deploying my website to Linux or Windows, I set my include paths like this: -

```
if(PHP_OS==="WINNT")
    include("..\\library\\chopper.inc");
else 
    include("/home/site/wwwroot/library/chopper.inc");
```

I'm sure this isnt the best way to do this!

Whats the correct way of setting the paths depending upon the environment?

Comment: Assume that Windows is no more a platform you should spend efforts on https://news-web.php.net/php.internals/110907

Comment: Does it work and cover your requirements?  Yes?  Move on and focus on something else that brings value to your code.

Comment: Yes, it works, but I want to do it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to use PHP's predefined constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR which gives you an OS-specific directory delimiter. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR separates the directories within the path: In Windows '' In other systems'/'

https://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php